# Oracle Outside In Parse SCCCA content

Tags: c, oracle, parsing, oracle-outside-in

I am using document [Oracle Outside In](https://docs.oracle.com/outsidein/851/oit/CNTAC/index.html) to output text content of pdf document.

I am using below parameters to pass to main function of `CASample.c` file from content access of https://www.oracle.com/middleware/technologies/outside-in-technology-downloads.html#

`C:\adobe-acrobat.pdf -u C:\adobe-acrobat.txt";`

Which gives me text in below format.

```
SCCCA_TEXT: dwSubType = 0x08020001, Number of Characters = 8, Character Set = 0x00030100.
    Outside 
SCCCA_TEXT: dwSubType = 0x08020001, Number of Characters = 3, Character Set = 0x00030100.
    In 
SCCCA_TEXT: dwSubType = 0x08020001, Number of Characters = 8, Character Set = 0x00030100.
    Unlocks 
SCCCA_TEXT: dwSubType = 0x08020001, Number of Characters = 9, Character Set = 0x00030100.
    Business 
SCCCA_TEXT: dwSubType = 0x08020001, Number of Characters = 10, Character Set = 0x00030100.
    Documents 
SCCCA_TEXT: dwSubType = 0x08020001, Number of Characters = 4, Character Set = 0x00030100.
    for 
SCCCA_TEXT: dwSubType = 0x08020002, Number of Characters = 1, Character Set = 0x00030100.
```

So how do I only get text out of it without metadata? like instead of above entire metadata content I only need `Outside In Unlocks Business Documents for`  or do I have to make my own parser to get those data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `tademo.vcxproj` as well in their downloaded files which does the job to extract text. It is a desktop application that you can convert to a library.

https://www.oracle.com/middleware/technologies/outside-in-technology-downloads.html#

After converting it to a library, I created the following function in `tademo.c` file which will take the input file and export the text file as output.

```cpp
int callableMain(char* inputPath, char* outputPath) {
    strncpy(szInputPath,inputPath, PATHSIZE);
    DAInitEx(SCCOPT_INIT_NOTHREADS, OI_INIT_DEFAULT);
    DoTextClose();
    dwBlockNum = 0;
    DoTextOpen(1);
    DoSaveTextAs(outputPath);
    DoTextClose();
    return 1;
}
```